# Plotting data with only horizontal and vertical connections in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, matlab-figure

## What I got

I got two data sources for instantaneous step frequency during a jogging session:

- A stride sensor attached to the subject's shoe
- Values calculated using a pedometer algorithm based on the accelerometer data of a smart phone attached to the arm of the subject

I'm trying to plot both together to get a intuitive comparison. The current plot looks as follows (orange from the stride sensor, blue from the algorithm):

[image: Step Frequency plot with two data sources]

What you can see, is that the calculated data always has right (90°) angles and does not connect the actual data points with linear functions. This accurately reflects what you would see when you have a look at your current step frequency. The value instantly changes to a new one each time it is updated. It looks this way because I deliberately put two data points with the same x-coordinate (timestamp) into my data set. This could look similar to the following code:

```
% on new cadence
c(i) = [t old_cadence];
c(i+1) = [t new_cadence];
```

## Question

So I'd like to get the stride sensor line plot to look the same way as my own data. Namely, it should only include vertical and horizontal connection lines. Is there maybe even a mode in the plot function that does that automatically or how would I do this? (I obviously want something better than looping through the elements)

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Not an answer but maybe take a look at [Interpolation techniques](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/interp1.html)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are looking for the [**stairs**](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/stairs.html) function:

```
y = randi([3,8],1,20);
x = 1:20;

stairs(x,y)
ylim([0,10])
```

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! I just was not sure what such a plot would be called and therefore never found the `stairs` function. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking for something like this?:

```
rng(620)
n = 10;
y = rand(1,n);
x = 1:n;

yy = nan(1,2*n-1);
yy(2:2:end) = y(1:end-1);
yy(1:2:end) = y;

xx = nan(1,2*n-1);
xx(2:2:end) = x(2:end);
xx(1:2:end) = x;

plot(x,y,'--o')
hold on
plot(xx,yy,'red')
```

[image]

Comment: This would also work but the solution by thewaywewalk using the `stairs` function does the same thing in one simple call ;)